# different storyboard in Xcode/iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6, ios-simulator

Suddenly my storyboard changed and it only displays one of the four textfields. When I run the code in the iOS simulator, I see all the four text fields.

I'm quite new to Xcode and would like to know how I can change my storyboard back so I see the same as in the simulator. It was right before.

A screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't updated the frames of the text fields to match your auto layout constraints. Click on tie-fighter icon (|-Δ-|) in the button bar under the canvas. Here you can choose "Update frames" for all views.

Comment: I have to place all element again now, but thank a lot!

Comment: The canvas will also shows a yellow warning triangle in the tree view with scenes (view controllers). Clicking on the icon will show you which view have frame that are not in line with the contraints.

Comment: The only problem I now have is that i can see the reset button (top left corner). Even with your answer i'm not able to get it back

Comment: Check the constraints of the button. Make sure the top and leading constraints are set correctly.

Comment: This is not possible because the button is not visible in the storyboard

Comment: It should be visible in the tree view. You can select the button from there and update its constraints.